# Intellij indicating error erroneously for Akka code in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, akka

Here's the setup:

- IntelliJ 13.1.2 (also tried 13.1.1)
- Akka 2.3.2
- Java 1.8 (also tried Java 1.7)
- Scala library 2.11 (also tried 2.10)
- Scala IntelliJ plugin 0.35.683
- Gradle 1.11 (IntelliJ is using this same installation)

I'm attempting to write some Java code that does some Akka stuff -- create Actors, send messages around, etc.  However, there are two pieces of code that throw type errors in IntelliJ but work just fine when compiling on the command line, and I'm at a loss as to how to resolve it.

1. Future#onSuccess()

   I have a call like this:

   ```
   Future<Iterable<Object>> sequence = Futures.sequence(...);
   sequence.onSuccess(new PrintResult<Iterable<Object>>(), getContext().dispatcher());
   ```

   where PrintResult is defined the same as here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/java/futures.html (i.e. PrintResult extends OnSuccess)

   However, I get a persistent red underline in IntelliJ on PrintResult:

   > onSuccess (scala.PartialFunction,java.lang.Object>, ExecutionContext) in Future cannot be applied
   >   to (PrintResult>, ExecutionContextExecutor)
2. I have a method relating to logging that can be simplified down to this:

   ```
   public void log(LoggingAdapter adapter, Logging.LogLevel level, String message) {
       adapter.log(level, message);
   }
   ```

   IntelliJ doesn't complain.  But if I try to build it on the command line, javac complains: `error: incompatible types: LogLevel cannot be converted to int`.  Adding level.asInt() makes the command-line errors go away, but now IntelliJ complains that adapter.log(level, message) doesn't take int for a level.

---

Any ideas what could fix the issues and make IntelliJ stop complaining?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an IntelliJ Scala plugin bug, plain and simple.  There are many bugs in the official bug tracker that [match](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL?q=good%20code%20red) this general description, all "good code red" or similar.  So I'll start there and perhaps open a bug if needed.